# Mysql SUM query returning "1" instead of correct much higher amount in pyqt5

Tags: python, mysql

Table example:

```
 "id","xxx', "xxxx" "xxxx", "dec"
```

where x = string, id = id, dec = decimal.

It just returns a 1 instead of the correct 274. When I run the query in MySql, the result is correct.

```
 def add_amounts(self):
    myTotal = 0
    mydb = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "TomM", "67706621TM", "expenses")
    cursor = mydb.cursor()
    myTotal = cursor.execute("SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM all_transactions;")
    print(myTotal)
```

Comment: What returns `1`?

Comment: Er, is that your actual password?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with PyQt5 so don't use that tag. Your project can use pyqt5 but that does not imply that you should use it in the question since in OS we do not help projects but concrete problems.

Comment: Not a python dev but this looks like you just got a success response for the query. the answer lies in cursor.

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't tell us the exact table structure, i don't know which criteria you use to summarize the amount.

But you have to use a query like this.

```
SELECT ColumnName, SUM(amount) as total FROM all_transactions
GROUP BY  ColumName;
```

So you get the sum of the amount for every what ever you have in ColumName .

Comment: no need to group by anything to get sum, it will simply sum the whole table. plus if you group by ColumnName you need to add it into field list to get a sum per columnname value.

Comment: He gets only **one** row back and he expects more than one as he says 274 rows, so he has to group .by, and not the sum of the hole table

Comment: he also says that when he runs SELECT SUM(amount) as total FROM all_transactions; in mysqlclient -  he gets the result he expects! So the select in question is returning the exact value he expects in the example above, just that he is not printing out the value of the response as that one hides in cursor.

Comment: total can also mean total of one customer, one product , one hotel room, you are speculating what he means. So lets wait and see, if he responds

Comment: I am reading what he wrote, and I quote: "It just returns a 1 instead of the correct 274. When I run the query in MySql, the result is correct." No mention of any rows, you added rows group bys etc...

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I did find a way to fix this. Instead of using SUM, I used select and fetchall to manually count the totals in the desire field. Sorry about lack of full information. I'll try to do better next time.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing the return value of `cursor.execute`, but the value you want - the result of the `SUM` - is in the first column of the first row of the resultset.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> conn = MySQLdb.connect('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'test')
>>> cursor = conn.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute("""SELECT SUM(assessment) FROM my_table;""")
1
>>> row = cursor.fetchone()  # Get the row
>>> result = row[0]          # Our result is in the first column of the row.
>>> print(result)
1552.50
```